# Angular2: can component be used inside another component template?

Tags: angular, components

Can I put component into another component template? 
E.g. declare component `ImageBox` with selector `image` and template `<img src="a.png"/>` and use it in another component template like `<div>Something there. And some image too <image></image></div>` — is this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what components are for

```
@Component({
  selector: 'image',
  template: '<img src="a.png"/>'
})
export class ImageBox {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'other',
  directives: [ImageBox],
  template: '<div>Something there. And some image too <image></image></div>'
})
export class OtherComponent {
}
```

You need to add components and directives to the `directives` list of the component where you want them to be applied. Angular then makes each tag that matches a selector of a component in `directives` such a component.

Comment: Thank thou, it worked. But why they used this approach? I'm already importing component from another file, is not that enough?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your question doesn't show or mention any import. I just created a demo element to show how to use one component in another.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

file 1

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ImageBox}  from './file 2';


@Component({
    selector:   'my-app',
    template:   '<div>Something there. And some image too <selectorNameImageBox></selectorNameImageBox> </div>',
    directives: [ImageBox]
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

---

file 2

```
@Component({
  selector: 'selectorNameImageBox',
  template: '<img src="a.png"/>'
})
export class ImageBox {
}
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

It sound weird when we write `component` , inside our `directives` list, but this is the way it is.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
    selector:   'my-app',
    template:   '<div>hello <innerComponent></innerComponent></div>',
    directives: [InnerComponent]  
   // mistake point (component in directive list)
})

export class AppComponent { }


@Component({
  selector: 'innerComponent',
  template: '<img src="a.png"/>'
})
export class InnerComponent {
}
```